# Problem with conditional rendering on React-native and AXIOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a big problem in react native, I have this:

```js
getreportbycode = async() => {
        this.setState({show : false})
        if(this.state.finder !== ''){
            const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('petra-token');
            this.setState({ jwt: token, sendform: true });
            axios.post('https://petrapi.herokuapp.com/emergence/find', {
                report_id : this.state.finder
        }, {headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${this.state.jwt}`
        }
            }).then(response => {
                this.setState({report: response.data.data, sendform:false})
                console.log(this.state.report)
                this.setState({mostrar : true})

        }).catch(error => {
            this.setState({finder:'', sendform:false})
            console.log(error)
        })
        }
    }
```

and this :

```js
report(report){
        if(this.state.show == true){
            return(
                <Card>
                    <CardItem>
                            <Left>
                            { report.alert.image == null
                            ?
                            <Thumbnail source={{uri:
                            'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-icon-2-1/100/user_5-15-512.png' }}
                            
                                style={{height: 50, width: 50}}/>
                            :
                            <Thumbnail source={{uri: report.alert.image}}
                            style={{height: 50, width: 50}}/>
                            }
                        </Left>
                        <Body>
                            <Text>
                                Creador: {report.user.name}
                            </Text>
                            {this.proccesbar(report.status)}
                        </Body>
                    </CardItem>
                    </Card>
)}
```

The problem is only when i tried catch "error" i have this error message :

[only when i tried catch error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq7fy.jpg)

Is there any way to do this correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are trying to obtain an image value of an undefined object.
So, instead of only check if `report.alert.image` is `null`, you could also verify if `report` and `alert` objects has value, like:

```
    (...)
    {
      (report?.alert?.image) ?
         <Thumbnail source={{uri: report.alert.image}} style={{height: 50, width: 50}}/>
      :
         <Thumbnail source={{uri: 'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-icon-2-1/100/user_5-15-512.png' }} style={{height: 50, width: 50}}/>
    }
    (...)
```